# Question regarding sets and universal sets and complements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to figure out this question in preparation for exam. This is not homework whatsoever, I'm just looking for a solution so if I encounter a similar program on this exam I will know what to do.

> Suppose that there are forty-three elements of the universal set U. Suppose that |A| = 17,   |B| = 16, |C| = 24, |A ∩ B| = 5, |A ∩ C| = 12, |B ∩ C| = 7 
>   and |$(A∪B∪C)^c$|=7. (this is a compliment) How many elements are there in(A∩B∩C)? If it isn’t possible to do this problem, please explain why.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any cookbook procedure you're supposed to follow here, beyond fooling around a bit with a Venn diagram and some imagination.

In this case, suppose that $|A\cap B\cap C|=x$. Then you can compute the sizes of $(A\cap B)\setminus C$, $(A\cap C)\setminus B$ and so forth as a function of $x$ -- for example, $|(A\cap B)\setminus C|=12-x$. Then sum every region of the Venn diagram that that makes up $A\cup B\cup C$.

Because you already know that $|A\cup B\cup C|=43-7$, this gives you a linear equation that you can solve to find $x$. Hopefully it will come out an integer!